# Compactness in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-writing

My question is once we have that if $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $E \subset \mathbb{R}^{m}$ then $\{x\}$ x $E$ is compact how to conclude that if $E \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $F \subset \mathbb{R}^{m}$ $E$x$F$ is compact, because the cartesian product is not associative, what could be done to prove this, thanks a lot in advance

Comment: You can also prove the result just using the definition of open sets: show that any covering of $E \times F$ by open sets has a finite subcover.  The tube lemma http://planetmath.org/tubelemma might be of use to you.

Comment: The use of the fact that $\{x\} \times E$ is compact will be more apparent if you do it this way.

Comment: thanks  is the proof is in the link ?in the link

Comment: well we haven't covered that topic yet :)

Comment: I'm sure you will be able to understand it (if you defined compactness as meaning that any open covering has a finite subcover).  This is a way of treating compactness which will work both for metric spaces like $\mathbb{R}^n$ as well as more general topological spaces.

Comment: Thanks a lot bit i cant use that resuly un my homework

Comment: That's fine, I mean I guess using the argument with sequences is the shortest route, but you can prove the tube lemma yourself, as well as the general result about product of compact spaces.

Comment: What definition of compactness are you using? Note that cartesian product is associative up to a homemorphism, but that fact seems to be completely irrelevant to your problem.

Comment: well the heine borel theorem :) that is all well an the one of the finite sub covers but I did not figure out how the later could help me :)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways.

We could use the characterization with sequences. Suppose $x_n:=(y_n,z_n)$  is a sequence in $E\times F$. Then $y_n$ is a sequence in $E$. Due to compactness there is a convergent subsequence $y_{n_k}$ in $E$. Then $z_{n_k}$ is a sequence in $F$. Due to compactness there is a convergent subsequence $z_{n_{k_i}}$ in $F$.

Then $x_{n_{k_i}}$ is convergent in $E\times F$.

Comment: thanks a lot Pp but how did we used that {x}xE is compact ?

Comment: @user162343 I thought you wanted to prove that if $E$ and $F$ are compact then $E\times F$ is compact.

Comment: right but using the fact above :) that was a lovely proof but i am asked to do it with that :)