# The cartesian product of compact sets is compact

Tags: analysis, proof-writing

my question this time is How to prove the following:

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $E \subset  \mathbb{R}^{m}$ compact, prove that $\{x\} \times E$ is compact

and form here how to conclude that if $E \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $F \subset \mathbb{R}^{m}$ compact then  $E$x$F$ is compact, because the cartesian product is not associative, what could be done to prove this, thanks a lot in advance  :)

Note: I have tried to do it using Heine-Borel in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ but I think there must be an easier way :)

My attempt of proving that if $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $E \subset  \mathbb{R}^{m}$ compact then $\{x\} \times E$ is compact,

We just need to verify that $\{x\} \times E$ is closed and bounded, further, we know that all finite set is compact, and then  $\{x\} $ is compact.

Note that $\{x\} \times E$ is bounded, we only need to take M=max{$m_1,m_2$} (where $m_1$ and $m_2$ are the bounds of $\{x\} $ and $E$).

Now, to see that $\{x\} \times E$ is closed we take the point $p=(x,c) \in \{x\} \times E$ such that $c$ is an accumulation point of $E$, and we know that $x$ is the only one of $\{x\}$ .

Let $\epsilon >0$ and we consider $B_\epsilon(p)$, now we will see that $B_\epsilon(p) \cap (\{x\} \times E) \not= \phi$, to this end we only observe that since $c$ is an accumulation point of $E$ and $x$ is a fix accumulation point then there exists $b \in E$ such that $(x,b) \in B_\epsilon(p) \cap (\{x\} \times E)$

**Am I right?**

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1133613/compactness-in-mathbbrn/1133624#1133624).

Comment: thanks a lot :) but how to do this with requirement of using the {x}xE fact and how to prove that :) thanks a lot any way?

Comment: How could there be an easier way than Heine-Borel? If $E$ is compact and $F$ is compact, then $E\times F$ is bounded and is closed. Both these properties are very easy to show. From them, it follows that $E\times F$ is compact, QED.

Comment: @user162343 You write that, small, in the corner of the paper, and in the center you do the other proof.

Comment: How do you show that is closed {x}xE and how do you conclude that ExF is compact with that fact ?

Comment: to bound {x}xE I took M=max{m_1,m_2} the bounds of each set, but the closeness is my problem :), and well the conclusion that then ExF is compact